# How to convert JavaScript `for` loop to Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I am new to Python and want convert this small JavaScript code to Python. How can I do that?

```
for (var y = 0; y < 128; y += 1024) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 64; x += 1024) {
        // skipped
    }
}
```

I searched a lot in Google, but found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `for` loops in Python

It can be easily converted using `range()` or [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) function. The [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) is an iterator version, which means it is more efficient (`range()` would first create a list you would be iterating through). Its syntax is the following: `xrange([start], stop[, step])`. See the following:

```
for y in xrange(0, 128, 1024):
    for x in xrange(0, 64, 1024):
        # here you have x and y
```

### Note

But I hope you have noticed, that due to the fact, that you are incrementing `y` and `x` with each respective loop by 1024, you will actually receive something similar to this:

```
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
```

or, in Python:

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

Anyway, it is just additional note about the code you have given as example.

Answer (score 6):

Your code will only perform one iteration in each loop, so you don't even need a loop:

```
y = 0
x = 0

# do whatever with x and y here
```

In general, you can use [`range([start], stop[, step])` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) to simulate such a `for` loop.

For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
```

becomes

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2)
```